# browser related question

Tags: browser

I get different behavior between IE and Mozilla.

Say for ex I have 2 buttons on my webpage. Button-1 and Button-2

In mozilla browser, when I click Button-1 then it process the click request of Button-1, while it is processing the request, immediately if I Click on button-2, browser will not proceed request for Button-2.

In IE browser, after clicking Button-1 If I immediately click Button-2 then it will first process request of Button-1 and then it will process request for Button-2.

Why there is different behavior for both browser for same web page?

PS. IE 8 and Mozilla 3

Comment: Browsers are different, sadly, thats the way it goes. Where some are better, they are worse in other areas.

Answer (score 0):

**Thats's life**

Browser differences are one of the biggest hurdles in modern web development.  You're best bet is to paste the code to let users take a look.